# Click Facebook 'share' button with selenium java

Tags: java, facebook, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I have to test this FB buttons:

[image]

Facebook buttons are inside an iframe. I switch to iframe, and I am able to find 'Share' button. But when webDriver clicks on it, the popup window doesn't show up. My code is:

```
WebElement iframeFacebook = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/iframe[1]"));
webDriver.switchTo().frame(iframeFacebook);
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'pluginButtonLabel') and contains(., 'Share')]")).click();
webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

I do the same for Twitter buttons, and it works. What is special about FB buttons?

**EDIT**

The HTML code of FB buttons:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:97px; height:35px; float:left" scrolling="no" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2Fmynumber26&width&layout=button&action=like&show_faces=false&share=true&height=35&appId=1454011268146569&locale=en_US">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html id="facebook" class="" lang="en">
    <body class="plugin gecko win x1 Locale_en_US" dir="ltr">
        <div class="_li">
            <div class="pluginSkinLight pluginFontHelvetica">
                <div>
                    <table class="uiGrid _51mz pluginConnectButtonLayoutRoot _3c9t" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="_51mx">
                                <td class="_51m- hCent">
                                    <td class="_51m- pluginButtonSpacer">
                                        <div class="pluginButton pluginButtonSmall" onclick="require(" Popup ").open("\/sharer.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffacebook.com\u00252Fmynumber26&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=share_button&app_id=1454011268146569 ", 670, 340);">
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="pluginButtonContainer">
                                                    <div class="pluginButtonImage">
                                                        <span class="pluginButtonLabel">Share</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="_51m-"></td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML of the buttons and anything else you think would be useful.

Comment: @JeffC, I added the HTML code

Comment: When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your xpath isn't finding the IframeFacebook, but is finding the button. The first click is setting the focus.

Try adding another click to see if this is the case. If it is try using Tag Name or ID locator for the Iframe.

If you want your life to be easier try:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/element-locator-for-webdriv/

Also, not to lecture, but it is general best practice to use Xpath locators as a last resort.

1. ID
2. Tag Name
3. Text
4. Href

Comment: Thank for help, but in the plugin we use, there is no ID or any identical tag that is easy to find. I added the HTML of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I've verified it. It is not in iframe.

Use below logic

```
String postNo="1";  // To click on share of first post in timeline
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'substream')]["+postNo+"]//span[@class='share_root']//span[text()='Share']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'substream')]["+postNo+"]//span[@class='share_root']//span[text()='Share']")).click();

//click on =>(Share Now friends) with below locator
By.xpath("//ul[@role='menu']//span[text()='Share Now (Friends)']")

//click on =>Share... 
By.xpath("//ul[@role='menu']//span[text()='Share…']")
```

**EDIT-I**

If we click on Share link once it is not opening below options (No idea  why?!). Try to click twice.

Comment: Thank for help, but I don't click in FB itself, our webapp has a button Share, a plugin, when you click, you have to login to your FB and share. I added the HTML code